# Map json on value

Tags: angular, http

When I do a http.get I get a jsonObject like this:

```
 "rights": [
    "VIEW_1",
    "VIEW_2",
    "VIEW_5",
AND LIKE 300 more]
```

And I only want to know that VIEW 1, 2 and 5 are in this array. And I was thinking of mapping this in to an interface but I dont know how to map on value only.

BR

Comment: When you say you only want to know what VIEW 1, 2 and 5 are - do you mean you only want to know what the first three elements of the array are? Or you want to know whether the array contains these?

Comment: @joe it can differ where there are in the list. They are names of access rights. So the array is a list over things they are allowed to see in the client

Answer (score 0):

So you want to turn

```
"rights": [
  "VIEW_1",
  "VIEW_2",
  "VIEW_5",
  ...]
```

into something like:

```
"rights": {
    "View1": true,
    "View2": true,
    "View3": true
 }
```

Where the rights is an interface `Rights`? If so, it's a pretty simple interface definition. Here's an example interface from the [typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html):

```
interface SquareConfig {
    color?: string;
    width?: number;
}
```

You would want one to represent your three booleans. (I'm not going to do it for you!).

The tricky thing will be converting the array into that object. You mention 'map', if you are refering to the JavaScript `map` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), this isn't going to work. It loops through and performs a transformation on each item in the array. You don't want to transform the items, and there's loads of ones you just want to throw away.

What you need to do is *search* for these items in the array. You can do this with a for loop, which would be the fastest. But you could also use the `find` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). The problem with that is you'll have to do it 3 times (and each one will loop through the array) so it's less efficient than just looping yourself, once, but looking for all three.